# pandas groupby - return the first row in a group that mets a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the example dataset below, I would like to return one row per `group` that shows the `obsnum` of the first row with a `score` less than 0.4.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
'obsnum': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
'score' : np.random.rand(12)})
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
df
  group obsnum  score
0   a     1   0.374540
1   a     2   0.950714
2   a     3   0.731994
3   a     4   0.598658
4   b     1   0.156019
5   b     2   0.155995
6   b     3   0.058084
7   b     4   0.866176
8   c     1   0.601115
9   c     2   0.708073
10  c     3   0.020584
11  c     4   0.969910
```

The returned result should be like this and stored in another dataframe.

```
group   obsnum  score
a         1     0.374540
b         1     0.156019
c         3     0.020584
```

I have tried this `df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x['score'] <= 0.4)` and this `df.groupby('group')['obsnum', 'score'].min()` but neither are what I am after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filter first and then [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df[df['score'] <= 0.4].drop_duplicates('group')
```

```
df = df.query('score <= 0.4').drop_duplicates('group')
```

---

```
print (df)
   group  obsnum     score
0      a       1  0.374540
4      b       1  0.156019
10     c       3  0.020584
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
df[df['score'].le(0.4)].groupby('group').first()

     obsnum     score
group                  
a           1  0.374540
b           1  0.156019
c           3  0.020584
```

Comment: `df[df['score'].le(0.4)].groupby('group', as_index=False).first()` ?

Comment: I will leave that to OP sir. He might need index.

Comment: Thank you! I accepted the other answer just because it came in first and did what I needed. But this is also really helpful, as is @jezrael's comment. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeap no worries. If it was help dont forget to vote atleast. Have a good day